# How to check who has access to folders using cmd or powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I wanted to ask how one would check who has access to subfolders in a certain directory on a server using either the CMD or Powershell?

Comment: Have you looked at the Microsoft documentation for [`Get-ACL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl?view=powershell-6)?

Comment: Powershell version -->
`$a = Get-Acl "\\PathToYourSubFolders";
$a.Access | FT -Autosize`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For NTFS permissions I like to use the [NTFSSecurity PowerShell Module](https://github.com/raandree/NTFSSecurity) as the output is similar to the windows permissions GUI.

It has simple commands for adding and removing permissions, which is an ugly process using the standard acls commands!

To see current NTFS permissions using this module:

```
Get-NTFSAccess -Path "\\server\share\folder"
```

Which would give an output like this:

[image: Get-NTFSAccess]

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `icacls`. From cmd type `icacls directoryname /t` replacing directoryname with the actually directory name to display all of the access permissions for the directory and subdirectories. The /t flag specifies to look in subdirectories. For more info just type in icacls into cmd or look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls